# Найти элемент в многоуровневом списке и добавить к нему новый уровень

Tags: c#

Не получается написать функцию, которая бы принимала на вход 2 аргумента `Func(ObservableCollection<Node> список, строковое_значение_для_поиска)`, искала по всем вложенным спискам и в случае совпадения `Name` добавляла еще один уровень данных.

```
public class Node
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Node> Child { get; set; }
}
ObservableCollection<Node> nodes;
nodes = new ObservableCollection<Node>
{
    new Node
    {
        Name = "1.1",
    },
    new Node
    {
        Name = "1.2",
        Child = new ObservableCollection<Node>
        {
            new Node {Name="2.1" },
            new Node {Name="2.2" },
            new Node {Name="2.3" },
        }
    },
};
```

Я понимаю, что она должна рекурсивно обходить все уровни, но у меня ничего не выходит.
После добавления должно быть примерно так.

```
nodes = new ObservableCollection<Node>
{
    new Node
    {
        Name = "1.1",
    },
    new Node
    {
        Name = "1.2",
        Child = new ObservableCollection<Node>
        {
            new Node {Name="2.1" },
            new Node {Name="2.2" },
            //После добавления
            new Node 
            {
                Name="2.3",
                Child = new ObservableCollection<Node> 
                {
                    new Node {Name = "3" } 
                }
            }
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: `но у меня ничего не выходит` код попыток в студию!

Comment: `void Method(ObservableCollection<Node> mass, string str){foreach(var a in mass) { if (a.Name == str) {
a.Child = new ObservableCollection<Node>
 {
 new Node {Name="2.5" }
};
Console.WriteLine(a.Name);
break;         
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine(a.Name + "!");
Method(a.Child, str);
}
 }
}`

Comment: Добавляйте код в вопрос, в комментах код нечитаем.

Answer (score 0):

Если решать в лоб то можно так:

```
void FindAndAdd(ObservableCollection<Node> listOfNode, string nodeName)
{
    for(int iter =0; iter < listOfNode.Count; iter++)
    {
        if(listOfNode[iter].Name == nodeName)
        { listOfNode[iter].Child.Add(new Node(){"x.x"}); }
        else
        { FindAndAdd(listOfNode.Child, nodeName) ; }
    }
}
```

В вашем случае, вы выполняете перебор через цикл foreach, где переменной `а` присваивается значение очередного элемента коллекции, и новый элемент вы добавляете не в коллекцию, а в переменную `a`, поэтому исходная коллекция у вас остается неизменной.